# my 2 point distance code returns syntax error in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, geometry, python-3.3

im really new in python and i wanted to make a code that asks you for the coordinates and returns you the distance between 2 points in the plane. This is my code:

```
def 2pointdistance(d):
    print(d)

xa = int(input("x1?: "))
xaa = int(input("x2?: "))
ya = int(input("y1?: "))
yaa = int(input("y2?: "))
xx = x1 - x2
yy = y1 - y2
xxx = xx ** 2
yyy = yy ** 2
xy = xxx + yyy
d = sqrt(xy)

2pointdistance(d)
```

hope you could please help me with this, i really liked this language
P.S.: Sorry for my english, im from chile

Comment: What is the syntax error? And why did you wrap a `print` statement in a `2pointdistance`? What is the point, and also please use meaningful variable names.

Comment: What is even more important, why you read data to the variables xa, ya ane then use x1 and x2? It has to lead to an error

Comment: oops i forgot to change the variables, i had it very clean and tidy, but then it came the errors and desperation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The function name should not start with the digit
2. Your whole code (logic) should be in the function, not just a print statement
3. You define different variables then are actually used

It should be something like

```
def distance(x1,x2,y1,y2):
    xx = x1 - x2
    yy = y1 - y2
    xxx = xx ** 2
    yyy = yy ** 2
    xy = xxx + yyy
    return sqrt(xy)

x1 = int(input("x1?: "))
x2 = int(input("x2?: "))
y1 = int(input("y1?: "))
y2 = int(input("y2?: "))

print( distance( x1, x2, y1, y2 ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

`2pointdistance` is not a valid name for a function. A name should not start with a digit.

[The docs](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers) explain it in all detail, but the point is that the function name should start with a letter or an underscore.